# Query for MS Access to insert record if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access

Here is a MySql query which is fine, but it does not work on MS-Access:

```
INSERT INTO ProcedureCodeModifier (ProcedureCode, Description)
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'A1', 'Dressing for one wound'
) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ProcedureCode FROM ProcedureCodeModifier
                  WHERE ProcedureCode = 'A1')
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LIMIT 1`.

That would be `SELECT TOP 1 ...` in Access, but it's not needed here.

Comment: @VigneshKumar: The query is `WHERE NOT EXISTS` which **is** available in Access.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19574640/2118383), I would do something like this:

Check to see if the code exists in the ProcedureCodeModifier table. If it doesn't, then run your `Insert Into` SQL.  You might have to play with this a bit, depending on if your Code field is a TEXT or an INT, but this should get you most of the way there.

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim sSQL as String

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ProcedureCode FROM ProcedureCodeModifier WHERE ProcedureCode = 'A1'")
```

This refreshes the dataset so you can get an accurate record count

```
rec.MoveFirst
rec.MoveLast
```

If your record count is 0, then the code isn't in the DB yet so you need to add it

```
If rec.RecordCount = 0 Then
  sSQL = "INSERT INTO ProcedureCodeModifier (ProcedureCode, Description) VALUES ('A1', 'Dressing for one wound')";
  DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL
EndIf
```

Always set your connection variables to Nothing so the connection closes!

```
Set db = Nothing
Set rec = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

"TOP 1" clause is must into main query.

```
INSERT INTO ProcedureCodeModifier (ProcedureCode, Description)
    SELECT TOP 1 
        'A1' AS ProcedureCode, 
        'Dressing for one wound' AS Description 
    FROM  
        ProcedureCodeModifier 
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 ProcedureCode, Description 
                    FROM ProcedureCodeModifier 
                    WHERE ProcedureCode = 'A1');
```

If `ProcedureCodeModifier` table is empty or if there is only one record in the table then "TOP 1" clause must be omitted in subquery. I have used Top 1 Clause in subquery for some performance issue.